# BigInteger HMAC conversion anomalie

Tags: java, hex, biginteger, hmac

I've a key:

```
byte: 0011100101010111000101111100101101100010100010111001010010000000
```

a message:

```
byte: 10110001
```

hmac output in hex:

```
HMAC-SHA256:    ca3871e40207fc0cd66558e4e4fa2817d283da605c15e4c941ff7945ad4be29f
```

So if I create a new BigInteger (test) like:

```
BigInteger test = new BigInteger(hmac);
```

And if I want to get the hex value back like:

```
System.out.println("\noutput: " + test.toString(16));
```

I get this:

```
output: -35c78e1bfdf803f3299aa71b1b05d7e82d7c259fa3ea1b36be0086ba52b41d61
```

Where is the problem? Or how can I calculate the hmac-sha256 from the message and use the BigIntegers from beginnning.

key, message and hmac are byte arrays.

If I try to convert byte "11010100" into BigInteger, it converts to negative "-101100"
Why BigInteger converts it negative? First bit is a sign bit, how can you disable sign bit?

Comment: what's the exact value of you `hmac` variable?

Comment: ca3871e40207fc0cd66558e4e4fa2817d283da605c15e4c941ff7945ad4be29f

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, because the code you've posted throws a `NumberFormatException`...

Comment: Show the code you are using. I also can't reproduce what you wrote in the edit...

Comment: try 
byte[] ttt = {1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0};
BigInteger Bmsg = new BigInteger(ttt);
and then
System.out.println("Bmsg: " + Bmsg.toString(2));
your result will be negative

Comment: No, I've run exactly the code in your comment and the result is positive. Post a minimal example that reproduces your problem. A few lines in a main method will do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a BigInteger constructor for setting the sign and magnitude separately, rather than the default of expecting a 2s-complement bitstring. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28int,%20byte%5b%5d%29).

Example:

```
Bmsg[i] = new BigInteger(1, msg[i]);
```